# Variable range in GoogleSheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
//create a copy for next week below in cell A31
function createWeek(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1!A4:AN30");
source.copyTo (ss.getRange("Sheet1!A31"));

var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 1;
}
```

I want to copy the range A4:A30 into the next empty row (in this case, row 31) BUT I'd like to do it every week so I need this row to be variable, because the next week the row will change. I could count the rows (numRows) but I don't know how to change the destination range so it can take into consideration the changing row (Sheet1!A???). THANKS!!

Comment: Can't you just do `ss.getRange("Sheet1!A" + numRows)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.getLastRow() + 1` `.getLastRow()` returns the last row containing data then + 1 to get the next row which will be empty.